# How to fix the texturing problem with the floor?

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I have this floor made out of tiles using array modifier and I wanted to apply the surface imperfection texture to it, but the problem is, it treats it like duplicates of a single object (which it basically is). So I want the surface imperfection texture to be continuous across all the tiles. How do I do this?
Thank you in advance!  [image]

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to organize your node tree or provide a file for someone to be able to help

Comment: I added the blender  file, but didn't include the texture, cause it all together it was around 100 MB. You can use any texture, I just want it to be continuous and spread across all the tiles. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an Empty. Add a UV Project modifier on the tiles and make sure its the last modifier in the stack. Set Object to your Empty. Now you can translate and scale the empty to manipulate the UV's.

[image]

[image]

You can use the free  [Poliigon Uber Mapping Node](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc) ([Download Link](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbEMtNTVsMS1kMlhhVEFld2lkUlg3UFRlRkg4QXxBQ3Jtc0tuU19haHlDbEJtUHNvWl9JakgzUXlPa2JkQzdycXZxekY1dGFVRW5fUW55M1NWVVlqWUlIckt2Ql8yNWNqay1rT2lOdjZxOVNXUUtVTXI5UHdxR3lLajVHeFQtajhfU2ctZDdpbUVLTFhjSVhmMTRkZw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fezs3ac34a26aa3f5ce6650303da779cb7c9b.s3.amazonaws.com%2FBlenderGuru_PoliigonNodes.blend)) that has mosaic rotation and noise to fix tilling patterns.

Comment: Huh. I've genuinely never thought of that. So simple. Thanks ;)

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. However still cannot figure out how to deal with tiling, because of the fact that tiles are duplicates of the same object, when I adjust the scale to suite my purposes, it still repeats itself on a larger scale and you can't fix it with mosaic rotation or smth similar. Any suggestions?